# how to load local models in external file magento 1.9?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to load a module from the local magento 1.9 folder into an external file. Any suggestion?

```
<?php
    require_once '../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();

    //... 
?>
```

Comment: I want to load a module from the local magento folder into an external file. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've used G-Translate to convert to english; There is also [an SO site for Pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). What is the issue you are having?